# Get an AD user's manager and input it into column of table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a `.csv` file that has the first and last names, as well as the email addresses of employees who've taken our security awareness training.
I want to take the email address column and compare it to the email address in AD, then take the manager from AD and put it into the appropriate column of my table.

This is what I have so far:

```
Import-Csv -Path "filename.csv" | 
    Select-Object "First Name",
        "Last Name",
        "Email",
        @{n="Manager";e={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).EmailAddress}},
        "Module Status",
        "Module Status Date" | 
    Select -f 30 | 
    Format-Table
```

Thanks!

Comment: And you don't get the desired result? Please update your question to make it a little more clear, what exactly your question ist.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{n="Manager";e={
    $self = Get-ADUser $_.Email -properties manager
    $manager = Get-ADUser $self.manager -properties emailAddress
    $manager.emailAddress
}
```

Of course you can write it shorter if you want to.